# wpa_supplicant for dual WLAN

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, redhat-enterprise-linux, wpa-supplicant

I've got wlan0 and wlan1. Each interface should connect to a different SSID.

I would like to use wpa_supplicant for both.

I can put the two networks in /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf, but how do I tell which one each interface should use?

(RHEL 6.3)

Answer (score 11):

You will need to create two new files in the following directory: `/etc/wpa_supplicant/`

The new files should be named with the interface name i.e `wpa_supplicant-wlan1.conf`

You should end up with two files like so:

for interface wlan0:

- file /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-**wlan0**.conf

for interface wlan1:

- file /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-**wlan1**.conf

**content of wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf file**

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

country=US

network={
        ssid="ssid0"
        psk="pass0"
}
```

**content of wpa_supplicant-wlan1.conf file**

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

country=US

network={
        ssid="ssid1"
        psk="pass1"
}
```

reboot PI and you should have SSID attached to an interface.

Comment: This was originally downvoted but it worked for me.

Comment: may i know how does this work? i cant seem to find any documentation on wpa_supplicant.conf file naming

Comment: @jaanhio - Sadly the documentation for that is a bit lacking; you have to read through the code inside `/usr/share/dhcpcd/hooks/10-wpa_supplicant` to figure that out—and that's part of the `dhcpcd` project anyways! See @Hannes' separate answer for more details.

Comment: thank you and @Hannes for clarifying! btw im a big fan of yours :D

Answer (score 9):

You create two separate `wpa_supplicant.conf` files, one for each interface. Then you specify which conf file goes with which interface when you invoke `wpa_supplicant`.  You use the `-N` option to show that you want to start describing a new interface.

This example comes right out of the `wpa_supplicant(8)` man page:

```
wpa_supplicant \
    -c wpa1.conf -i wlan0 -D hostap -N \
    -c wpa2.conf -i ath0 -D madwifi
```

Comment: Thanks. This works in my `NixOS`

Comment: How would you use this if wpa_supplicant is being ls being run as a service e.g. via systemd?

Answer (score 3):

@jaanhio Sorry can't comment, thus as an answer. Can somebody please move it to the comments? I think it is quite interessting to know why creating a file wpa_supplicant-wlan1 works.

junaid's answer is correct for debian. On debian (or at least Raspbian Buster) dhcpcd controls wpa_supplicant in `/usr/share/dhcpcd/hooks/10-wpa_supplicant` you find

```
if [ -z "$wpa_supplicant_conf" ]; then
        for x in \
                /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-"$interface".conf \
                /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf \
                /etc/wpa_supplicant-"$interface".conf \
                /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf \
        ; do
                if [ -s "$x" ]; then
                        wpa_supplicant_conf="$x"
                        break
                fi
        done
fi
```

So there is these behaviour with wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf and wpa_supplicant-wlan1.conf files "documented"

Thus you also don't need a reboot when changing. Just exec `sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd`

Comment: Your comment submitted as an answer cannot be converted to comment due to its length.  If you are unable to submit a comment you must earn that privilege.  Asking for comment, submitted as an answer to be converted into a comment, is not allowed.  **I don't agree your answer is even a comment, but since you believe it's a comment, I went ahead and flagged it for a moderator to review**