# Can one “wpa_supplicant” support Ethernet LAN and WLAN?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wpa-supplicant

The product I’m working on supports Ethernet only, and we are planning to support WLAN as well. I’m trying to figure out whether same [`wpa_supplicant`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/wpa_supplicant) can support both of Ethernet and WLAN or we have to have two separate `wpa_supplicants` for Ethernet and WLAN, has anybody tried the similar thing before?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself but I would expect it to work. Setting up wpa_supplicant for two interfaces is covered here: [wpa_supplicant for dual WLAN](https://superuser.com/questions/469039/wpa-supplicant-for-dual-wlan/470940#470940)

…but that's an example with two WLANs, not one WLAN and one LAN.

To set up wpa_supplicant for a wired Ethernet LAN, I believe you have to add "-D wired" to your WPAOPTS, and ap_scan=0, for that interface. But you can find documentation for that elsewhere.

Answer (score -3):

`wpa_supplicant` is a component that implements key negotiation with a WPA Authenticator and it controls the roaming and IEEE 802.11 authentication/association of the wlan driver.

It is designed to be a “daemon” acting as the backend component controlling the wireless connection.

It has nothing to do on Ethernet.

Comment: WPA Enterprise and WPA2 Enterprise, that is, the non-PSK versions of WPA and WPA2, use 802.1X authentication and wpa_supplicant acts as the 802.1X supplicant.  wpa_supplicant can also be used as your 802.1X supplicant on a wired interface.