# I want my raspberry pi 3 b to automatically connect to a wireless network via antenna

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I want my raspberry pi 3 b to automatically connect to a wireless network via antenna (not with integrated one), the interface is wlan1. I want to do this only via terminal. Is there a wpa_supplicant word key that lets me to choose the interface?

Comment: Have you tried to search the web? What did you find? Why doesn't it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can e.g. use the wpa_supplicant command line interface `wpa_cli` to connect to a network. As you want to use the interface `wlan1`, you simply have put it as parameter.

This is an example for `wpa_cli` in interactive mode (replace AP_NAME with the name of your AP, passphrase with the passphrase of the AP and 0 with the number that is printed to stdout after ADD_NETWORK):

```
sudo wpa_cli -i wlan1

> ADD_NETWORK
> SET_NETWORK 0 ssid "AP_NAME"
> SET_NETWORK 0 psk "passphrase"
> ENABLE_NETWORK 0
> quit
```

You can find the reference for `wpa_cli` [here](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?wpa_cli).

If you want a permanent connection, please follow the official [documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md) and update the wpa_supplicant.conf file.

Details regarding two wlan interfaces can be found e.g. [here](https://superuser.com/q/469039/857120).

Comment: Did that and it worked! But when I reboot it doesn't automatically connect to the AP again.

Comment: I have updated my answer to address the permanent connection.